# Sitecore 9 Session End Pipeline issue

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I am trying to send some anonymous data into analytics and browse it in experience profile.

I set `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` into layout and added reference to `mvc.extensions`.

Set the timeout for the session to 1 and browsed page. After 1 minute I can see in logs following error:

```
ERROR PostSessionEndPipeline failed.
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.EntityOperationException
Message: Operation #0, Conflict, DeviceProfile {0396d6cd-af6c-44d5-9844-496b528677bf}
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
```

Firstly I fixed device detection using the SC patch and thought that's gonna solve the issue but not.
I've checked everything that I could but still can't find the issue.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hi benihamalu did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solved it?

Comment: link to sitecore patch:  https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.203066/releases

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the patch suggested by Sitecore. I was facing the same issue and I am able to resolve it by deploying patch, from below link, to all the sitecore instance (CM, Reporing, Processing and CD). Please refer below link to download the patch.

https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.203066/releases